# Why isnt UWB technology used for big file transfers?

Tags: wifi, file-transfer, wireless, uwb

I am working on my thesis right now and i have to compare near field communication technologies (WPAN) which can transfer files.

everybody is talking how great UWB is for locating things and how fast it is, but there is no one (but apple) that used it for file transmission. But why? Its has a bigger bandwith then Wifi Peer to Peer?

Apple seems to use it for airdrop and both for android and ios there is an API to develop based on this technology. But it looks that its designed for location services and only work with specific devices for location. So I would not be able to use it for example to transfer files between iOS/Android and a Raspberry Pi in Near Field.

Can anyone explain me, if UWB can transfer files and, or why i should use Wifi-Direct instead of UWB if I want to transfer Files that are >1GB with the fastest speed (but without internet of course)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

IR-UWB is more popular than MC-UWB

UWB modulation schemes can broadly be divided into two categories

- multi-carrier UWB (MC-UWB): used for high throughput data transmission, 480 Mbps
- impulse-radio UWB (IR-UWB): used for localization, sensing.